# Is there a platform with the format of Stack Exchange where you get paid for participating?

Tags: earned-income

## Preface

When reading the [tour](https://money.stackexchange.com/tour) page, I was hesitant on asking this question until I came accross this point for asking good questions:

> Strategies for earning and saving more money

I thought this fit under "strategies for earning more money" so this was my impetus for asking.

## Question

Is there a platform that is similar to a stack exchange, except you can get paid for participating?

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be a better subject in one of the chat rooms or metas. Right now it reads like a "shopping list" question, which is considered off topic per the help guide: https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: There are many sites where you can get paid to do homework. You won't make much, student typically don't have much money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quora has a [partnership program](https://www.quora.com/partners/info) where you get paid to **ask questions.**

That always seemed backwards to me, but it seems like they are trying to expand the range of content on their site.

If you want to get paid to share your expertise, there are probably better channels than Q&A sites (i.e. YouTube, blogs, courses, etc.)

Comment: @isakbob https://www.quora.com/partners